# Kubernetes: How to get other pods' name from within a pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to find out the other pods' name running in the same single-host cluster. All pods are single-application containers. I have pod A (written in Java) that acts as a TCP/IP server and a few other pods (written in C++) connect to the server.

In pod A, I can get IP address of clients (other pods). How do I get their pods' name? I can't run kubectl commands because pod A has no kubectl installed.

Thanks,

Comment: can you try `nslookup <ip-address>`  for reverse dns ?

Comment: @P... I tried that. nslookup <ip-address> returns host name of pod which may not match the pod name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly call kube-apiserver with cURL.

- First you need to have a serviceaccount binded to clusterrole to be able to send requests to apiserver.

  `kubectl create clusterrole listpods --verb=get,list,watch --resource=pods`

  `kubectl create clusterrolebinding listpods --clusterrole=listpods --serviceaccount=default:default`
- Get a shell inside a container

  `kubectl exec -it deploy/YOUR_DEPLOYMENT -- sh`
- Define necessary parameters for your cURL, run below commands inside container

  `APISERVER=https://kubernetes.default.svc`
  `SERVICEACCOUNT=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount`
  `NAMESPACE=$(cat ${SERVICEACCOUNT}/namespace)`
  `TOKEN=$(cat ${SERVICEACCOUNT}/token)`
  `CACERT=${SERVICEACCOUNT}/ca.crt`
- Send pods list request to apiserver

  `curl -s -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H 'Accept: application/json' $APISERVER/api/v1/pods | jq "[ .items[] | .metadata.name ]"`

Done ! It will return you a json list of "*kubectl get pods*"

For more examples, you can check [OpenShift RestAPI Reference](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/rest_api/api/v1.Pod.html). Also, if you are planning to do some programmatic stuff, I advice you to checkout [official kubernetes-clients](https://github.com/kubernetes-client).

Credits for jq improvement to [@moonkotte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15537201/moonkotte)

Comment: I'd probably add to this answer is possible to install `jq` on host, it'll give a simple and pretty output with `curl -s -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H 'Accept: application/json' $APISERVER/api/v1/pods | jq "[ .items[] | .metadata.name ]"` command. `-s` for silent mode.

Comment: Thanks! I added your improvement :)